# Electrical measurements of Chicago substation from where can I get it?

Tags: mains, power-electronics, power-engineering, electronic-load

I am doing a project on electrical load prediction using machine learning. Machine learning involves creating models based on past data. For creating these models where can I get data regarding electrical measurements of Wider Chicago substation? 
If you provide any links it will be very helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not EE

Comment: @ScottSeidman: What's more EE than electrical power distribution?

Comment: Wasn't my DV, but this is a request for data-- I assume about power usage to feed a model of load prediction, and not instrumentation or methods of measurement.  I read it as "where can I find out how much power goes through this substation as a function of time?".  If the OP clarifies, and it turns out not to be this, I'll remove my close vote.  Perhaps "not clear what you're asking" would have been more appropriate.

Comment: You could always measure usage for your own house and extrapolate.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: What you mentioned in your comment is spot on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

This is an archive for machine learning datasets..There is not the one which you want but there are datasets of some other Power Substations one in India.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, although the nature of this question does invite such answers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to contact the electric company that runs whatever substation you want to get data about.  They may have the data to give you.  Otherwise, it's going to be a long and difficult process to convince them to connect your equipment to theirs to allow you to collect the data.  Basically, if they aren't already doing it, then there is no data to have.